# Timer class, not increasing count

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm not sure where I did wrong. I don't see any error, but the count isn't increasing.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTimerLabel: UILabel!

let myTimer = Timer()    

@objc func myTestFunc() {
   var count = 0
   count+=1
   myTimerLabel.text = String(count)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

             Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector  
            (myTestFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not increasing because each time myTestFunc() called, it reinitialize the count variable with zero. So, declare count variable outside myTestFunc().

Answer (score 0):

You have to make structure in right way

check this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTimerLabel: UILabel!

let myTimer = Timer()    
var count = 0

//MARK: - view did load
override func viewDidLoad() {
  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector (myTestFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }

 //TODO:- here implement your funtion 
 @objc func myTestFunc() {
 count+=1
 myTimerLabel.text = String(count)

 // if you want to stop your timer
 myTimer.invalidate()
}
```

Good luck